# output to jade the appropriate value from an object sent from express

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, iteration, pug

I'm trying to figure out how you would retrieve the appropriate information on the page when users go to `"/users/:name"`. what I'm trying to do is print out "welcome user2" if user2 logged in and the same for the other users. the way I was thinking of doing it is to pass along the param from `"/users/:name"` and check if the param is equal to the `username` value print out that value.(not sure if that is a safe way to do it) how do I cycle through my particular list of objects and compare it to the param?

I get this sent to my jade document

`{ list: 'userList', users: [ { password: 'pass1', username: 'user1' }, { username: 'user2', password: 'pass2' }, { username: 'user3', password: 'pass3' } ], address: '14459 70 th st city NY', desc: '3 floors', __v: 0, _id: 56baf181356641f01213295a }`

that get's sent because I do this:

```
app.get("/users/:name", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.params.name)
    User.findOne({"users" : { $elemMatch: { username : req.params.name}}}, function(err, doc){
        console.log("test ", doc)
        res.render("users", {result : doc, name : req.params.name});
    })

})
```

jade:

```
html
    head
    body
        p= result
        p Welcome #{result.users[0].username} #{name} // prints out--> Welcome user1 user2 ||| when user2 signs in
        p= result.address
        h3= result.desc
        a(href="/logout") logout
```

Comment: Basically you have an object where you are getting each time the first username by `result.users[0].username` always equals `user1`.

So the question is what authorisation check do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I already authorized. A user could sign in with any of the username and password combination from the users array(they could view and change the same data). now I just want to print a welcome message for the signed in user. I know that `result.users[0].username` just looks at the first object. I just want retrieve the right username from those objects. I think it's a good iteration exercise for me to learn. not sure to use each or for loop

Comment: I want to compare `name` to the username in the objects and print out the username value but there are three objects. I could print out the username by just interpolating `name` but I want to get it from the object.

Comment: sure, see my answer below. all appropriate data can be grabbed from `user` variable in the jade markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you probably want to go with this, to select appropriate user object for the given param input:

```
app.get("/users/:name", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.params.name)
    User.findOne({"users" : { $elemMatch: { username : req.params.name}}}, function(err, doc){
        console.log("test ", doc)
        var users = result.users;
        var currentUser = {};

        for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
          if(users[i].username === req.params.name)
            currentUser = users[i];
        res.render("users", {result : doc, user : currentUser });
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks I'll examine this more later I have to go somewhere now. thanks for your answer. I was thinking of doing some iteration in the jade file but you did it in the route request. That's fine but since I was thinking of doing it in jade if you could show how to do it there too that would be extremely helpful. and I will definitely accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: sure just go with this notation, if you want to do that in Jade, but I wouldn't expose all users data to a layout anyway. http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/